# Remover resultados de acordo parâmetro do CASE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Conforme segue a consulta abaixo, preciso remover da consulta SQL os resultados que tenha o campo **CLIENTE_UNICO** igual a 'MÚLTIPLAS COMPRA NO PERÍODO'.

```
SELECT
NFE.CD_CLIENTE AS "COD. DO CLIENTE",
EMP.NOME_COMPLETO AS "CLIENTE",
(
CASE COUNT(NFE.NF) WHEN 1
THEN 'ÚNICA COMPRA NO PERÍODO'
ELSE 'MÚLTIPLAS COMPRA NO PERÍODO'
END)
AS "CLIENTE_UNICO"

FROM FANFISCA NFE
LEFT JOIN GEEMPRES EMP ON EMP.CD_EMPRESA = NFE.CD_CLIENTE

WHERE NFE.DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/05/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/08/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

GROUP BY NFE.CD_CLIENTE, EMP.NOME_COMPLETO
```

Segue abaixo também o resultado da consulta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia de como "excluir" esses resultados com "MÚLTIPLAS COMPRA NO PERÍODO"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT
    NFE.CD_CLIENTE AS "COD. DO CLIENTE",
    EMP.NOME_COMPLETO AS "CLIENTE",
COUNT(NFE.NF)
    AS "QUANTIDADE_COMPRAS_PERIODO"
    
    FROM FANFISCA NFE
    LEFT JOIN GEEMPRES EMP ON EMP.CD_EMPRESA = NFE.CD_CLIENTE
    
    WHERE NFE.DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/05/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/08/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    
    GROUP BY NFE.CD_CLIENTE, EMP.NOME_COMPLETO,COUNT(NFE.NF)
    HAVING COUNT(NFE.NF)= 1
```

veja se é esse o resultado que você esperava